# Mining clearcase

Tags: clearcase, clearquest

We recently had an incident at work where one of our sysadmins deleted the ClearQuest database without any backups.

We are left trying to use the data in Clearcase to rebuild activities and files modified due to this incident.

What would be a good plan of action for making a list of the activities and the files that changed due to this unexpected deletion?

Comment: step #1: fire the admin(s) who neglected to do backups.

Comment: Were you using ClearCase UCM?

Comment: Yes we were using ClearCase UCM.

Comment: Small comment re @MarcB's comment. I've dealt with people who thought that since they had filers with "snapshot" capability, they were safe. Until said filers had hardware failures. Not pretty.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes and no...

The ClearCase activity "name" will be the original CQ record ID and the headline of the activity will be the headline/summary from CQ. Unfortunately, that's about all (other than the change set) that it does contain from CQ.

You would have to create a new CQ user DB and reconnect the UCM projects to that user db. I'd make sure that the new CQ DB has a different name, if only to make it easy to see what's a leftover...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can recover the CQ activities when the DB is gone. The easiest way probably is just disconnect the UCM integration to CQ, then all these CQ activities will become local CC activity.